# Beaglebone pwm pins

Tags: beagleboneblack

[image: Beaglebone pin layout]
According to this pin layout of the BB, only 7 pins support pwm output. However, I tried `PWM.start()` on other pins and it seemed to work fine. Can anyone list which other pins support pwm output and why? Or if checking whether a pin supports pwm using that function is incorrect, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pin layout shown in your attached image is the DEFAULT pin layout of beaglebone black, while mode of each of pins on beaglebone headers (except power, GND, Reset and Analog input pins) can be changed to another mode different from default.

you should check AM3358/9 datasheet (depending on the revision of your board) for this purpose. Each of pins might support up to 8 modes (8 peripheral can control a pin) but only one of the peripherals may control each pin at a time. It is recommended to do not try to change the mode of other pins to utilize pwm if your application does not enforce you, because it's not straightforward to change pin mode in Linux. However, if you have to change pin mode of some pins, you can begin by searching for these expressions: `Device-Tree`, `uboot overlay` or `kernel module` programming.